# Cannot convert special (ASCII/UTF-8) characters

Tags: php, ascii

I am trying to take a group of characters which are ASCII and it contains things like `☺ ☻ ♥`.

When I try to `echo` them out with PHP I get `?` for each one. And when I try to use `htmlentities()` it works for the heart but returns some jambled stuff like : `â˜º` for `☺`.

Entirely what I am trying to do is convert a string of text that I have no control over, but is in ASCII and display it with HTML and store it with SQL.

I am sorry if this is a poorly formed question, but I am not sure how this whole section of conversion works.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you try to put <meta charset="UTF-8"/> in the html code before?

Comment: An ASCII string ***cannot*** contain characters like ☺, ☻ or ♥. Please learn [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) to narrow down your problem and what you're trying to do here.